# OutOfMemoryError Android

Tags: android, out-of-memory, arrays

My application was running fine about 5 days ago! Today, I try to run it, and its going absolutely nuts!

I'm getting this message in logcat before it finally throws the outofmemoryerror

```
01-06 04:14:17.088: D/dalvikvm(454): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 5702 objects / 326856 bytes in 76ms  
01-06 04:14:17.228: D/dalvikvm(454): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 680 objects / 157944 bytes in 57ms
01-06 04:14:17.228: I/dalvikvm-heap(454): Grow heap (frag case) to 2.860MB for 121834-byte allocation
01-06 04:14:17.288: D/dalvikvm(454): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1 objects / 81232 bytes in 60ms
01-06 04:14:17.378: D/dalvikvm(454): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 5 objects / 192 bytes in 65ms
01-06 04:14:17.388: I/dalvikvm-heap(454): Grow heap (frag case) to 2.957MB for 182746-byte allocation
....and so on...
```

and then finally this error comes up:

```
01-06 04:24:49.218: E/AndroidRuntime(511): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
01-06 04:24:49.218: E/AndroidRuntime(511):  at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:97)
01-06 04:24:49.218: E/AndroidRuntime(511):  at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:136)
01-06 04:24:49.218: E/AndroidRuntime(511):  at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:272)
01-06 04:24:49.218: E/AndroidRuntime(511):  at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:452)
01-06 04:24:49.218: E/AndroidRuntime(511):  at appsbidder.clientstuff.Utils.openURL(Utils.java:285)
01-06 04:24:49.218: E/AndroidRuntime(511):  at appsbidder.clientstuff.Utils.getFeatured(Utils.java:224)
01-06 04:24:49.218: E/AndroidRuntime(511):  at appsbidder.FeaturedAppsActivity$GridViewAdapter.<init>(FeaturedAppsActivity.java:45)
01-06 04:24:49.218: E/AndroidRuntime(511):  at appsbidder.FeaturedAppsActivity.onCreate(FeaturedAppsActivity.java:28)
01-06 04:24:49.218: E/AndroidRuntime(511):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-06 04:24:49.218: E/AndroidRuntime(511):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
01-06 04:24:49.218: E/AndroidRuntime(511):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-06 04:24:49.218: E/AndroidRuntime(511):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-06 04:24:49.218: E/AndroidRuntime(511):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-06 04:24:49.218: E/AndroidRuntime(511):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-06 04:24:49.218: E/AndroidRuntime(511):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-06 04:24:49.218: E/AndroidRuntime(511):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-06 04:24:49.218: E/AndroidRuntime(511):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-06 04:24:49.218: E/AndroidRuntime(511):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-06 04:24:49.218: E/AndroidRuntime(511):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-06 04:24:49.218: E/AndroidRuntime(511):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-06 04:24:49.218: E/AndroidRuntime(511):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I THINK I narrowed it down to this block of code, but I don't know why it doesn't work! It was always working fine before. The only problem I can think of is that now it has to fetch more data than before, so somewhere an overflow is happening, but where??

```
public JSONArray openURL(String urlParams, String url)
  {


    HttpsURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
      System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
      //Create connection
      connection = (HttpsURLConnection)new URL(url).openConnection();
      connection.setRequestMethod("POST");


      connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
      "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

      connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + 
          Integer.toString(urlParams.getBytes().length));
      connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US"); 


      connection.setUseCaches(false);
      connection.setDoInput(true);
      connection.setDoOutput(true);

      //Send request
      DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (
                  connection.getOutputStream ());
      wr.writeBytes (urlParams);
      wr.flush();
      wr.close();

      //Get Response    
      InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
      String line;
      JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
      while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
          ja = new JSONArray(line);
      }
      rd.close();
      return ja;

    } catch (Exception e) {

      e.printStackTrace();
      return null;

    } finally {

      if(connection != null) {
        connection.disconnect(); 
      }

    }

  }
```

Answer (score 3):

What I can see you should look at this:

```
      while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
          ja = new JSONArray(line);
      }
```

Since the error is trown at the readLine method call.

```
01-06 04:24:49.218: E/AndroidRuntime(511):  at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:272)
01-06 04:24:49.218: E/A ndroidRuntime(511):  at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:452)
```

You should try this:

```
char[] buffer = new char[8064];
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is), buffer.length);
```

And use read instead of readLine

```
rd.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)
```

There are many examples on this.

EDIT:

From my old project:

```
readResponse(InputStream inputStream) {

ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream ();
byte[] buffer = new byte[8064];

while(true) {
int rd = inputStream.read(buffer)
if(rd == -1)break;
stream.write(buffer, 0 , rd);
}

stream.flush();
buffer = stream.toByteArray();
String response = new String(buffer);
inputStream.close();

return response;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't necessarily work since the first argument of the read method needs a char[] rather than the byte[] .

Comment: yeah, I actually just looked at it. sorry the REAL problem is that I can't use this way because my "line" variable is a string. only the readLine is applicable here, unless im missing something

Comment: Well, you are assinging a value to 'line' which is to big and causes a exception. If the 'response' contains line breaks (\n) you could split the String and retreive your lines that way.

Comment: Do you mean that the value is too big for the type String?

Answer (score 2):

Probably here:

```
while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
```

If response contains big json in single line, then you can have a OutOfMemoryError on this line. You can verify this by checking what response is coming manually.

Comment: how would I fix it, if the JSON is very big?

Answer (score 0):

I think this line of code is wrong :

```
JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
      while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
          ja = new JSONArray(line);   // in every step of loop, you create an object, that is wrong for memory
      }
```

instead use :

```
JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
      while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
          ja.add(line);
      }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried it, still the same problem. do you think it can be the json is just too big?

Comment: I don't think, but after a small search, I found a thread about this, check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886599/android-outofmemoryerror-loading-json-file